# MySQL 3 table search with one table not directly related

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have 3 tables :

- `wp_users` - stores main information about all users,
- `wp_usermeta` - stores additional information about users(first/last name/etc),
- `wp_friends` - stores information about friends from third party services related to a specific user from `wp_users`

If you are not familiar with WordPress, you can see the structure of both tables at http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

The structure of my custom table `wp_friends` is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_friends (
    id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    uid bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    fr_id VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL default '',
    service VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL default '',
    name VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL default '',
    photo VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY uid (uid),
    KEY fr_id (fr_id),
    KEY service (service)
)`
```

The `uid` column is corresponds to the `ID` column in the `wp_users` table - this is how I determine which record corresponds to which user.

What I'm trying to do is to create a query that will look in all of the three tables for a match against a keyword. Here is what I've come with so far(the first part was generated by a search function of WordPress):

```
SELECT 
    wp_users.ID,wp_users.display_name,wp_users.user_login,
    wp_users.user_email,fr.fr_id,fr.name,fr.photo,fr.service
    FROM wp_users

    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id)

    LEFT JOIN wp_socialaccess_friends AS fr ON fr.uid = 2

    WHERE 
    (
        (user_login LIKE '%nik%' OR user_nicename LIKE '%nik%')
        AND 
        (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) != '0')
    )
    OR ( fr.uid = 2 AND (fr.fr_id LIKE '%nik%' OR fr.name LIKE '%nik%'))

    GROUP BY wp_users.ID,fr.fr_id ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

In the above query, the keyword is "nik"(which also matches a `user_login` column). The `fr.uid` part is needed so the returned results are only for the current user. The query fails in the following ways:

- It returns all rows from the `wp_friends` table(because the `user_login` column is matched as well), that have `wp_friends.uid = 2`
- It returns rows that have `wp_friends.uid = 2` but matched with users where `wp_users.ID != 2`

Is it possible to create a single query, that would return the selected columns, but will also prevent duplicates?

Comment: The `wp_socialaccess_friends` and `wp_friends` tables are the same - just a typo there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about joining on a sub-select like:

```
SELECT 
    wp_users.ID,wp_users.display_name,wp_users.user_login,
    wp_users.user_email
    FROM wp_users

    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id)
    left join(
      select fr_id, uid,name,photo,service from wp_socialaccess_friends where
            uid = 2 and
            (fr_id LIKE '%nik%' OR name LIKE '%nik%')
        ) AS fr ON wp_users.ID = fr.uid 

    WHERE 
    (
        (user_login LIKE '%nik%' OR user_nicename LIKE '%nik%')
        AND 
        (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) != '0')
    )

    GROUP BY wp_users.ID,fr.fr_id ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

Comment: It throws me the error ` for the right syntax to use near 'where uid = 2 and (fr_id LIKE '%nik%' OR name LIKE '%n' at line 8`(probably because you missed `from` ?) . But if I add `FROM` I get `Unknown column 'fr.uid' in 'on clause'`, even if it is `wp_socialaccess_friends.uid` - which doesn't make any sense to me, since the column is selected correctly...

Comment: My fault - I rushed my post.  The updated query has the `uid` column added to the sub-select and I fixed the missing `from`.

Comment: I added the `fr.*`(the ones I need) columns to the `SELECT` and it's working great for returning the friends, but it only does so, when the `ID` column matches `uid` AND `user_login`. I mean that if I change the keyword to something different than "nik" I won't get any results because the `user_login` column no longer matches that. Besides the search no longer returns results from `wp_users`. Like I said, I'm not quite sure whether what I want is achievable in single query - do you think that I should do two separate queries and then sort them with PHP?

Comment: Could it be it's because the '2' is hardcoded, or did you change that when you changed the 'nik'?  One other thing -`fr.uid = wp_users.ID` correct?  If it is, maybe try your original query with `LEFT JOIN wp_socialaccess_friends AS fr ON fr.uid = 2` changed to `LEFT JOIN wp_socialaccess_friends AS fr ON fr.uid = wp_users.ID` and `OR ( fr.uid = 2 AND (fr.fr_id LIKE '%nik%' OR fr.name LIKE '%nik%'))` changed to `OR ( fr.fr_id LIKE '%nik%' OR fr.name LIKE '%nik%')`.  Seems like one of these two approaches should work.

Comment: I believe it is meant to be hardcoded, because I only need to find the friends of the user with `ID = 2`, which makes for `wp_users.ID = wp_friends.uid = 2`. I'm testing your suggestion right now, but with not much success so far...